# Why can't you have several version of a r-package in a given r-library

Tags: r, r-package, r-library

Is it possible to access several versions of the same package in a given library ? I see many projects online like [miniCRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/miniCRAN/index.html) or [versions](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/versions/index.html) or [cranium](https://github.com/shapenaji/cranium) but they all allow the same thing which is allow a user to **build** a given version of a package.

My problem is that I have several users that need to **run their code as the same prod user** so they might need different versions of the same package.

Is there something that would enable me to do essentially

```
R) library(my_package, version='1.0.1')
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is not possible to install multiple versions of a package in a library. But you can have multiple libraries on you computer and and install the various versions of the packages into these.

You can give a path for the library to be used when you install a package:

```
install.packages("my_package", lib = "path/to/library")
```

In this way, you could install different versions of a package to different libraries. When loading a package, you can again specify from which library you want to load it:

```
library(my_package, lib.loc = "path/to/library")
```

There are also packages that help you to use separate libraries for different projects. One example is [packrat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/packrat/index.html). Unfortunately, I have never used it myself, but there is a "Quick Start Guide" on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/).

Comment: packrat solves the problem of 'how do I deploy a package truly self contained as it contains all the libraries it uses' but does not solve the 'how do I acces any package of any version'

Comment: @statquant I don't think that it is possible to 'deploy a package truly self contained'. The packrat webpage speaks of "R projects" not "R packages". So, assuming that you are not using various versions of an R package in the same project, packrat should be able to do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I do not think so... packrat is to build packages not libraries (set of built packages)

Comment: Well, as I said, I haven't used it, so I might be wrong. It's just that the docs say that packrat "creates a private package library" for a project and never mentions that it can be used to build packages (http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/, section "Basic concepts"). But it's not useful to fight about this here, so I suggest that we agree to disagree on this...